# Is Vedic Science true?

Tags: mathematicians, mathematical-physics

I somewhere read that ancient Indian science was so advanced even in 2000 B.C. (or may be even before this) that Indian scientist and mathematicians calculated the value of distance between sun and Earth. They even found the value of $\pi$. They made a piller made of iron which resists rusting.They did even more. It is said that they wrote all their discoveries in scriptures which can be found even today. They called it Vedic science.

So my question is: Is it possible that they could have found and done all these things? If yes, how? If no, how?

I am not claiming that they did those things. But it has confused me for so long.

EDIT :

Here are some sites in the favour:

[1](http://forum.davidicke.com/showthread.php?t=202595)

[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKyn3FDaTYc)

[3](http://www.dandavats.com/?p=10946)

And here are some against it :

[1](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~dani/vmtimeart.pdf)

[2](http://nirmukta.net/Thread-Links-on-Pseudoscience-and-Superstition)

[3](http://asfak-ur-rahman.blogspot.in/2011/11/list-of-scientific-errors-in-hindu.html)

Comment: "I read somewhere" is such a useless thing to say.

Comment: @fdb i added some sites...i know these are not the verified sources but its just to give an idea what is happening out there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** "Vedic science".

There is an ancient [Indian mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_mathematics) as well as an ancient [Indian astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_astronomy).

They are comparable (from an historical point of view; not in term of "better or worse") to ancient [Egyptian mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_mathematics), [Babylonian astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_astronomy),  [Chinese astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_astronomy).

---

Regarding the question :

> Is Vedic Science true?

if you consider e.g. [Jyotisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_astrology), i.e. the traditional Hindu system of astrology, we have the *Siddhānta*:  the branch of Jyotisha devoted to calculating the position of the planets and other heavenly bodies :

> According to this theory, the earth is motionless and is not considered a planet. Seven planets (Moon, Mercury, Venus, Sun, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn) revolve around the earth.

Thus, this theory is false.

Regarding *Samhitā* : Mundane astrology, and *Horā* : Predictive astrology, they are clearly not scientific at all in any "modern" sense.

Comment: and what about the ' [Iron pillar of delhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_pillar_of_Delhi) '. It was science...it resists rusting...

Comment: @manshu - See [History of metallurgy in South Asia : Iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_metallurgy_in_South_Asia#Iron) : "Indian Wootz steel was held in high regard in Europe, and Indian iron was often considered to be the best." The [Iron pillar of Delhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_pillar_of_Delhi) is a masterpiece of ancient Indian metallurgy.

Comment: then isn't metallurgy a part of science...?

Comment: @manshu - it depends... if you are saying that they developed the *techniques* needed because they know the chemistry principles or the quantum mechanics laws underlying them, the answer is clearly : they do not. But ancient civilizations developed fairly good technolgies without knowing the scientific principles that we used today to explain them.